# Convert a array List to a simple list

Tags: python, arrays, list, scikit-learn

I try to use classification_report from sklearn.metrics:

```
sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, target_names=None, sample_weight=None, digits=2, output_dict=False)
```

As input for prediction and label i've got one list each with the following form:

for pred:

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
       2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2])]
```

for true:

```
[array([2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3,
       2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2,
       2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])]
```

for the sklearn-function above i need a simple list. The array produces an error:

> ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

I tried `.tolist()` already but didn't work for me.

I am searching a possibility to convert my array-list [?] to a simple list.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please use code blocks for your code (the `{}` icon).

Comment: Perhaps you need the first element of your single-element list instead: `y_true[0]` and `y_pred[0]`, have you tried that?

Comment: why are you sending a 1 length list with an array inside it? Just send the arrays directly?

Comment: "I am searching a possibility to convert my array-list [?] to a simple list." You can pass numpy arrays in without a problem. But for some reason you are wrapping the array's inside a list. So instead of `pred = [np.array([0, 0, ...,])]` do `pred = np.array([0, 0, ...,])`. If you can show the code generating `pred` and `true` it might be more obvious where you mistake is that has put them into a single element list.

Comment: @VomDorfe see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of those objects is already a list, each of which contains a single element, which is an array.

To access the 1st element and convert it to a list, try something like:

```
x = [array([2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3,
   2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2,
   2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])]
x_list = list(x[0])
```

And x_list will contain the array element in list form.

Answer (score 0):

### Way 1: Just index the lists e.g. `pred[0]`

**Code:**

```
pred = [array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2])]

test = [array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2])]

classification_report(pred[0], test[0])
```

### Way 2:

Reform it to match `sklearn` requirements:

```
pred = [array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2])]

test = [array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2])]

flat_pred = [item for sublist in pred for item in sublist]
flat_test = [item for sublist in test for item in sublist]

print(classification_report(flat_pred,flat_test))
```

Comment: It's already flat, just leave off the outer `[]`. i.e. `pred = array([0, 0, ..., ])`.